# How to create dropdownlist Disabled in ASP.NET Razor MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    <div class="form-group">            
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseStatus, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })    
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("statusList", String.Empty, new { @disbled = disabled})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStatus)       
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am new in ASP.NET MVC5 and RAZOR. I just want to create a disabled dropdownlist. I have already created SelectList name "statusList". Through which I am trying to call the status. but I want to make it disbled and make one status as by default

Answer (score 5):

`Html.DropDownList` has [these overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). you have to use one which takes `htmlAttributes` as a parameter.

you can use  [**this overload:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492256%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@Html.DropDownList("statusList", null, String.Empty, new { disabled = "disabled"})
```

you have to use following overload:

```
Html.DropDownList(
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

See [**Details Here On MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492256%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use like this.For an Empty drop down list with out any value  you should use.

```
@Html.DropDownList("statusList", new List<SelectListItem> { }, String.Empty, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

and if you want to populate values as well you can use like this.

```
@{
  List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
  list.Add(new SelectListItem {  Value="1", Text="Test Status"});
}
@Html.DropDownList("statusList", list , String.Empty, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 0):

hi your problem its when you try to disabled ,i advice you to change this

@Html.DropDownList("statusList", String.Empty, new { @disbled = disabled})

by below code

@Html.DropDownList("statusList", String.Empty, new { @disabled = true})

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> itemEtatRenseig = listeEtatRens.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
                Value = c.EtatReseigne,
                Text = c.EtatReseigne,

        });

        VewBag.EtatRenseign = new SelectList(itemEtatRenseig, "Value", "Text", Rapport.RapportList.FirstOrDefault().EtatReseigne);
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("EtatRenseign",null,"--Sélectionner un etat--", new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: if you can add more description, for other users, it might be more valuable.